# Doctrine 2: Count entity's related entities without hydration

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have the doctrine structure like this.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="entity_deviceProfile")
 */
class DeviceProfile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TranscodeProfile", inversedBy="deviceProfiles")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="entity_deviceProfile_rel_transcodeProfiles_transcodeProfile")
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    protected $transcodeProfiles = null;
}
```

I want to have method `getTranscodeProfileCount()` in `DeviceProfile` class.

So I add the following function to `DeviceProfile`:

```
public function getTranscodeProfilesCount() {
    if (!$this->transcodeProfiles->isInitialized()) {
        $this->transcodeProfiles->initialize();
    }
    return $this->transcodeProfiles->count();
}
```

It works ok except the memory usage and performance. Hydrating the whole collection takes a lot of memory and time. I have hundred of thousands of `transcodeProfiles` and the number is growing.

Is there a way to get the count of records without hydrating the collection?

PS: I know that I can do it from outside the entity by running `count()` query with `$em`. But unfortunately this functionality is part of the huge app and updating all calls to the function is a huge work. So I'm looking for the way to solve the issue within an existent functionality.

Answer (score 2):

There is feature of Doctrine 2 called '[Extra Lazy Associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html)' that solved my problem.

It is exactly what I need. For the count it doesn't hydrate the collection but do the `count()` query instead.

Together with [Doctrine filters](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html) it allows to seamlessly filter associated entities as well.